# meteor OSX Error: SQLITE_CANTOPEN: unable to open database file

Tags: macos, meteor, osx-elcapitan

I ran the following command:

```
$ meteor create myapp
```

And got following error message:

> Retrying after error { [Error: SQLITE_CANTOPEN: unable to open database file] stack: [Getter] }
>   Retrying after error { [Error: SQLITE_CANTOPEN: unable to open database file] stack: [Getter] }
>
> /Users/santosh/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.1b51q9m++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:278
>                         throw(ex);
>                               ^ Error: SQLITE_CANTOPEN: unable to open database file
>       at Object.Future.wait (/Users/santosh/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.1b51q9m++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:398:15)
>       at [object Object]._.extend.*execute (/tools/packaging/catalog/catalog-remote.js:368:22)
>       at /tools/packaging/catalog/catalog-remote.js:145:10
>       at [object Object].*.extend.*retry (/tools/packaging/catalog/catalog-remote.js:157:16)
>       at new Db (/tools/packaging/catalog/catalog-remote.js:144:8)
>       at [object Object].*.extend.initialize (/tools/packaging/catalog/catalog-remote.js:703:15)
>       at /tools/cli/main.js:748:20

Does anyone know what causes this issue and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

The issue was due to permissions. Following steps worked. Sharing out problem and answer for KB.

```
$ sudo meteor create myapp
```

Created a new Meteor app in 'myapp'.

To run your new app:

```
cd myapp                                    
meteor
```

If you are new to Meteor, try some of the learning resources here:
  https://www.meteor.com/learn

Comment: Great, accept your own answer if that solves the issue