# Why is meteor failing to open the database file?

Tags: ubuntu, meteor, filesystems, readonly, busybox

Every time I try to fire up my meteor app by:

```
sirbt@sirbt-K54C:~/Bgain$ meteor
```

I get the below error messages:

```
Retrying after error { [Error: SQLITE_CANTOPEN: unable to open     database file]
errno: 14, code: 'SQLITE_CANTOPEN' }
Retrying after error { [Error: SQLITE_CANTOPEN: unable to open database file]
errno: 14, code: 'SQLITE_CANTOPEN' }
/home/sirbt/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.4.2_3.1qvo8je++os.linux.x86_32+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_32/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/meteor-promise/promise_server.js:190
  throw error;
  ^

Error: SQLITE_CANTOPEN: unable to open database file
at Error (native)
 => awaited here:
at Promise.await (/home/sirbt/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.4.2_3.1qvo8je++os.linux.x86_32+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_32/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/meteor-promise/promise_server.js:39:12)
at Db._execute (/tools/packaging/catalog/catalog-remote.js:355:8)
at /tools/packaging/catalog/catalog-remote.js:144:10
at Db._retry (/tools/packaging/catalog/catalog-remote.js:156:16)
at new Db (/tools/packaging/catalog/catalog-remote.js:143:8)
at RemoteCatalog.initialize (/tools/packaging/catalog/catalog-remote.js:694:15)
at /tools/cli/main.js:844:20
```

Following is a little background on my system that might help decipher the issue. I run Ubuntu 15:10.

Lately I noticed that every time I start my PC, it starts in the Ubuntu fail safe mode. Whatever I do I end up in the Busybox mode:

`(initrafs)`

To start Ubuntu, I then have to feed in this command:

`fsck -y /dev/sda1`

It also seems like the my file system is now a Read-only file system. 
A little research also indicates that error am getting while trying to run meteor is due to a lack of permission.

Kindly help me restore my settings so that I am able to fire-up my meteor app.

Answer (score 1):

For me, It is because of the permission issue.

Check the folder permission - `.meteor`

```
sudo chown -R renjith:renjith /home/renjith/.meteor/
```

This solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create your Meteor project with sudo, reference to  [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34255912/meteor-osx-error-sqlite-cantopen-unable-to-open-database-file)

Comment: I would like to be able to start the meteor app as Ive always done with out having to use sudo.

Answer (score 0):

I manged to solve the issue by restoring the system.

I restarted my PC, and it started in the Ubuntu fail safe mode. The fail safe mode runs the Busybox mode that shows:

`(initrafs)`

I then feed in this command:

```
fsck -y /dev/sda1
```

Ubuntu now starts and I can log into the desktop. 
I then re-installed the desktop.

by pressing Ctrl+Alt+F1

I logged in with my username and pass.

Then I pasted this:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-session
```

This restored my system. Now I am able to fire up my meteor app without any issues.

Thanks to [fsck problem when booting Debian stretch](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/233076/fsck-problem-when-booting-debian-stretch)